# AngularJS - Ionic : execute code in controller when coming back to it

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-controller

I'm new in AngularJS Community and I'm developping my first app with this Framework.

I created a new controller with this code :

```
.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
alert('test');
})
```

And my route :

```
.state('app.account', {
    url: "/account",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/account.html",
        controller: 'AccountCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

The alert popup is shown the first time I access to the controller. But, if I change URL and I come back to AccountCtrl (with a classic html a), the alert popup is not shown again.

Could somebody explain to me why ?

Thanx for your help !

Comment: That' strange, normally the controller will be instantiated every time the url changes. Are you developing with Ionic framework? In Ionic the views and controllers are cashed. You could add a listerner to the scope '$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', myUpdateFunction'.

Comment: Hi Stefan, yes I'm using Ionic Framework. Where I have to add this listener ? In my controller ?

Comment: I add an example as answer to your question. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ionic Framework views and controllers will be cached by default. You ma add a listener to the views scope to receive a notification when the view is re-active again. For more information see: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/
and http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/

You may also disable the cache on a view `<ion-view cache-view="false">`

```
.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function () {
            // update campaigns everytime the view becomes active
            // (on first time added to DOM and after the view becomes active after cached
        alert('test');
    });
})`
```

Answer (score 1):

to reload Controller each time in ui router,  use `reload: true` option on the .state

```
$stateProvider
.state('app.account', {
      url: "/account",
      reload: true //forcefully reload route and load controller again
})
```

Comment: Hi AB, your answer doesn't work for me :/ Is it because i'm using Ionic Framework ?

Comment: reload is whether as state should be rebuild after a param change http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state